# How can I tag or give a document of text a topic?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have set of documents and corresponding set of tags for those documents

ex.

Document-"Learned Counsel appearing for the Appellants however points out that in the..etc etc"

Tags - "Compensation, Fundamental Right"

Now I have multiple documents with their corresponding tags and I another test set of data without any tags what NLP techniques do I use to give these documents tag? Do I use text classification or topic modeling can someone please guide or suggest some ideas.

Comment: This is a supervised, multi-class text classification problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use two approaches:

1- rule based (extract common words in each tag and classify documents with them)

2- machine learning

if you have a large scale training data you can use machine learning to classify documents:

you can use this approaches:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08398

https://medium.com/@armandj.olivares/using-bert-for-classifying-documents-with-long-texts-5c3e7b04573d